# Is there a way to check for an echo text value?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm currently checking for a value in my database and if it checks out I echo "Completed" to that field, and if it doesn't check out then it will echo "In Progress"

That's completely fine, but I want to create a little function that will check if any echo on the page equals "In Progress" and if it does when the user clicks the generate report button it will pop up saying 'Are you sure you want to generate the report it has not been fully completed.

I feel like it's simple but I just can't get my head around it, cheers in advance for any help.

```
<?php
if($report -> reportdata -> C1c){echo("Completed");}
else{echo("In Progress");}

<button type = "submit" class="btn btn-success bt-lg" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to generate the report it has not been fully compleated.');">
?>
```

Comment: Why not just show button __only__ when status is `In progress?`

Comment: Because I'd still like them to be able to generate the report without fully completing it, this is just a QOL for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this -

```
If($report == "C1c" /* or what ever the value youre checking for is correct*/)
{
/*Button here to just submit the form if the report is completed*/
<button></button>
}else{
<button type = "submit" class="btn btn-success bt-lg" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to generate the report it has not been fully compleated.');">
}
```